# Azure Service fabric - Application and Service types

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Offlate I have been reading Microsoft documentation on Application Types and Service Types and although the document is quite extensive, can someone explain the concepts in easy language?

To make it easy, I have jotted down my understanding below. Please correct me if I am wrong.

An Application type is a categorization of applications. For example, Let's say we have 2 clusters.

**Cluster 1** : Non-Prod cluster will have 2 application types QA and Dev. This means the same application code will be present within two application types but with different configs

**Cluster 2** : Prod cluster will have 2 application types UAT and Prod. This means the same application cpde will be present within two application types but with different configs

The same concept goes for Service Type. One service could be present in different service types

Let me know if my understanding is correct?

Regards Tarun

Comment: I am not sure it would 100% help but I once tried to formulate this for myself and I ended up writing a blog [post](https://olegkarasik.wordpress.com/2018/10/03/service-fabric-handbook/#object-model). Hope this helps somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceType` vs `Service instance` is similar to `Class` vs `Object`.
The type defines the service, and the instance is a service.
The same concept applies to `ApplicationType` vs `Application`.

As you said, you'd can have multiple instances of the same `Application Type` (e.g. one per tenant) and you can also choose to have different `Application Types` for every hosting environment, if you want.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-model).